# Configure RollingFileAppender programatically Not able to write logs to the specific folder using logback in my spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have this Loggerutils class which returns me the logger object.

```
public class Loggerutils {

 public static Logger createLoggerFor(String string, String file) {

      LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
      PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
      ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n");
      ple.setContext(lc);
      ple.start();
      RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>  rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
      FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
      rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern("pilogs.%i.log.zip");
      rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
      rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(3);
      rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
      rollingFileAppender.setFile(file);
      rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
      rollingFileAppender.setContext(lc);
      rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
      rollingFileAppender.start();
      Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);
      logger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
      logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
      logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
      return logger;
    }
}
```

I use below lines of code to instantiate logger

```
Logger logger = Loggerutils.createLoggerFor("UserController", "UserControllerFile");
logger.info("Inside User controller..........");
```

and in application.properties I configured

```
logging.path=E:/LOGS/WebAPI
```

but in the given location only one file is being created and that is spring.log. My requirement is I want my log files to be created at specified location.
I don't have logback.xml in my resources folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes to createLoggerFor() method. And now it works.

```
@Component
public class Loggerutils {


private static String logDirectory;

@Value("${logging.path}")
public void setLogDirectory(String path){
    logDirectory = path;
}


public static Logger createLoggerFor(String loggerName, String fileName) {
    Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);

    LoggerContext loggerContext = rootLogger.getLoggerContext();
    loggerContext.reset();

    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rfAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    rfAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
    rfAppender.setFile(logDirectory+loggerName+"\\"+fileName);

    FixedWindowRollingPolicy fwRollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
    fwRollingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
    fwRollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(logDirectory+loggerName+"\\"+"pilogs.%i.log.zip");
    fwRollingPolicy.setParent(rfAppender);
    fwRollingPolicy.start();

    SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> triggeringPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
    triggeringPolicy.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
    triggeringPolicy.start();

    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
    encoder.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n");
    encoder.start();

    rfAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
    rfAppender.setRollingPolicy(fwRollingPolicy);
    rfAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(triggeringPolicy);
    rfAppender.start();

    rootLogger.addAppender(rfAppender);

    return rootLogger;
  }

}
```

and logging.path in my application.properties is,

```
logging.path=E:\\LOGS\\WebAPI\\
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Remove loggerContext.reset(); to print logs in different files

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the full path of the log file instead of just the filename. Try this

```
public class Loggerutils {

 public static Logger createLoggerFor(String string, String file) {

      LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
      PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
      ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n");
      ple.setContext(lc);
      ple.start();
      RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>  rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
      FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
      rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern("pilogs.%i.log.zip");
      rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
      rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(3);
      rollingPolicy.setContext(lc);
      rollingPolicy.start(); 
      rollingFileAppender.setFile("E:/LOGS/WebAPI/" + file);
      rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(ple);
      rollingFileAppender.setContext(lc);
      rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
      rollingFileAppender.start();
      Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);
      logger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
      logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
      logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
      return logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, not working :( .tried rollingFileAppender.setFile("E:/LOGS/WebAPI/" + file) and rollingFileAppender.setFile("E:\\LOGS\\WebAPI/" + file) as well. Is anything else I need to change along with that?

Comment: I just reviewed the code and found that you never started rollingPolicy, please use rollingPolicy.start(). Updated the answer as well.